# Same response for different requests in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, request, response

I have application for report generation. where scenario is - 
1.Login
2.Select particular type of report say ABC report(page will load for ABC report with records)
3.select the Page Size from 50 to 100 from drop down

I have recorded scenario in jmeter and when i run it. In response i got same response for all above request .. why this is happening any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have NOT added the `HTTP Cookie Manager` which you could find under `Config Element` to store the cookie information as part of your login response. Add that under your Test plan element and retry.

Please do note that JMeter recorded scripts might have some information specific to the session which you used to record (some randomly generated id). But if you play back, your application might not accept that as it has been already used. So, It is your responsibility to find and parameterize accordingly.